# pandas group by and count total by adding new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe, it looks like this:

```
user_id indicator_id    direction_up
    1   11              true
    2   12              true
    2   13              false
    1   14              true
    1   11              false
    3   15              false
```

I want to count total quantity of indicators for each user, and also count quantity of indicators where user set diresction_up as true and separately count where user set diresction_up as false

so it would something like this:

```
user_id total_quantity_of_indicators    quantity_direction_up_True  quantity_direction_up_False
    1                   3                               2                           1
    2                   2                               1                           1
    3                   1                               0                           1
```

I've tried to make it like this:

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'direction_up']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

but how to add total quantity of indicators i just have no idea, i'm new to this

how can i make it?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['user_id'], df['direction_up'], margins=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby and merge:

```
res=df.groupby('user_id').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'total_quantity_of_indicators'})

res=res.merge(df[df.direction_up==True].groupby('user_id').size().reset_index(), how='left').fillna(0).rename(columns={0:'quantity_direction_up_True'})

res=res.merge(df[df.direction_up==False].groupby('user_id').size().reset_index(), how='left').fillna(0).rename(columns={0:'quantity_direction_up_False'})

>>>print(res)

   user_id  total_quantity_of_indicators  quantity_direction_up_True  quantity_direction_up_False
0        1                             3                         2.0                            1
1        2                             2                         1.0                            1
2        3                             1                         0.0                            1
```

Answer (score 0):

`cross_tab` and then row sum:

```
(pd.crosstab(df.user_id, 'quantity_direction_up_' + df.direction_up.astype(str))
   .assign(total_quantity_of_indicators = lambda df: df.sum(1))
   .reset_index())

direction_up  user_id  quantity_direction_up_False  quantity_direction_up_True  total_quantity_of_indicators
0                   1                            1                           2                             3
1                   2                            1                           1                             2
2                   3                            1                           0                             1
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, just a variation on `crosstab`:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['user_id'], df['direction_up'], margins=True)
   .add_prefix('quantity_direction_up_')
   .drop('All')
   .rename(columns={'quantity_direction_up_All': 'total_quantity_of_indicators'})
   .loc[:, ::-1]
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   user_id  total_quantity_of_indicators  quantity_direction_up_True  quantity_direction_up_False
0        1                             3                           2                            1
1        2                             2                           1                            1
2        3                             1                           0                            1
```